# Unexpected behavior when sorting strings with letters and dashes

Tags: c#, sorting

If I have some list of strings contain all numbers and dashes they will sort ascending like so:

```
s = s.OrderBy(t => t).ToList();
```

66-0616280-000
66-0616280-100
66-06162801000
66-06162801040

This is as expected.

However, if the strings contain letters, the sort is somewhat unexpected. For example, here is the same list of string with trailing A's replacing the 0s, and yes, it is sorted:

66-0616280-00A
66-0616280100A
66-0616280104A
66-0616280-10A

I would have expected them to sort like so:

66-0616280-00A
66-0616280-10A
66-0616280100A
66-0616280104A

Why does the sort behave differently on the string when it contains letters vs. when it contains only numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: That is weird. I didn't believe it until I ran it myself...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the default `StringComparer` is culture-sensitive. As far as I can tell, `Comparer<string>.Default` delegates to [`string.CompareTo(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which uses the current culture:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture. For more information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see [`System.Globalization.CompareOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then the page for `CompareOptions` includes:

> The .NET Framework uses three distinct ways of sorting: word sort, string sort, and ordinal sort. Word sort performs a culture-sensitive comparison of strings. Certain nonalphanumeric characters might have special weights assigned to them. For example, the hyphen ("-") might have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op" appear next to each other in a sorted list. String sort is similar to word sort, except that there are no special cases. Therefore, all nonalphanumeric symbols come before all alphanumeric characters. Ordinal sort compares strings based on the Unicode values of each element of the string.

("Small weight" isn't quite the same as "ignored" as quoted in Andrei's answer, but the effects are similar here.)

If you specify `StringComparer.Ordinal`, you get results of:

```
66-0616280-00A
66-0616280-10A
66-0616280100A
66-0616280104A
```

Specify it as the second argument to `OrderBy`:

```
s = s.OrderBy(t => t, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

You can see the difference here:

```
Console.WriteLine(Comparer<string>.Default.Compare
    ("66-0616280104A", "66-0616280-10A"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare
    ("66-0616280104A", "66-0616280-10A"));
```

Comment: I think this answer isn't really complete without the explanation of how the ordering differs. Saying how to fix it is good but its nice to know why the original failed which is what the question actually was (though has been explained by Andrei).

Comment: I agree, the combination of Andrei and Jon's answer is really the answer, wish I could select both.

Comment: @BBauer42, I think you should select Jon's, so when other run into the same problem they will see how it can be solved. Not everyone cares for explanation, but everyone cares for solution.

Comment: @Andrei: Hopefully my edit contains a sufficient explanation as well now :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, Jon. A much more complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the remark from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The Compare(String,
>   String) method does not consider such characters when it performs a
>   culture-sensitive comparison. For example, if the following code is
>   run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a culture-sensitive comparison
>   of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates
>   that the two strings are equivalent.

So it looks like you are experiencing this ignorable character case. If we assume that the `-` symbol has a very small weight in comparison, the results of the sorting look like this.

First case:

```
660616280000
660616280100
6606162801000
6606162801040
```

Second case:

```
66061628000A
660616280100A
660616280104A
66061628010A
```

Which makes sense

Comment: Very nice explanation of how culture-sensitivity affects this scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually an *ignorable* character here, as I believe it's just a normal ASCII hyphen. I suspect it's the "small weight" aspect which comes into play - see my edited answer for details.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yeah, I see. Still not clear though when the hyphen does affect the culture-sensitive sorting. Small weight is still weight, and it should come in play somewhere. Are you aware of such examples?

Comment: @Andrei: I suspect it means that "a-b" will come before "a--b", whereas if the characters were completely *ignored*, they would be sorted equally. Just a guess though :)